# Set didSet for outlet collection

Tags: swift, iboutlet, didset

I have a few picker view that I added in a outlet collection, they should have different properties that I need to add them in their didset
for example, here is the outlet collection

```
@IBOutlet var dataPickers: [UIPickerView]! {
  didset {

  }
}
```

The problem is, i have to say that if the first member of `dataPickers` do that things, but I don't know how I can say that in the didset.

could anyone help me on this? thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `didSet` is called when the whole array is set. If you want to apply properties to just the first picker in the array, then you can do something like:

```
@IBOutlet var dataPickers: [UIPickerView]! {
    didSet {
        if let first = dataPickers.first {
            first.someProperty = someValue
        }
    }
}
```